# Dispatching a saved request

Tags: zend-framework

I am trying to dispatch a saved request after successful authentication.

```
$this->getRequest()->setParams($requestObj->getUserParams())
                                                    ->setActionName($requestObj->getActionName())
                                                    ->setControllerName($requestObj->getControllerName())
                                                    ->setModuleName($requestObj->setModuleName())
                                                    ->setDispatched(false);
```

The problem I have run into is the header part of the layout appears twice in the rendered page. I am guessing the Controller Action helpers have dispatched them for the first request, and again for the second request. Please help me how can I avoid this from appearing twice.

Answer (score 0):

After successful authentication its always better to redirect user through http redirect .

```
$this->_helper->redirector('action','controller','module');
```

You can disable layout if you like by doing

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->disableLayout();
```